# Python ValueError: time data '02-01-2020' does not match format '%d/%m/%y' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working on a dataset for machine learning but I have an error for the date that not matching. I am tried both times with different strings in format `"%d-%m-%y"`, `"%d/%m/%y"` but it is not worked for me. What can I do so that problem will solve. What can I do as dataset dates are in a different format?

````
df_MR['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_MR['Date'], format = "%d-%m-%y")```

ValueError: time data '30/01/20' does not match format '%d-%m-%y' (match)


df_MR['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_MR['Date'], format = "%d/%m/%y")```

ValueError: time data '02-01-2020' does not match format '%d/%m/%y' (match)
````

Comment: This is a `pandas` and `datetime` question (tags added), and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had some success using the infer_datetime_format argument of to_datetime in a small example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['02-01-2020', '03-02-20', '03/02/2020', '04/05/2020']})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['a'], infer_datetime_format=True)
0   2020-02-01
1   2020-03-02
2   2020-03-02
3   2020-04-05
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do as in dataset dates are in different format ?

1. fix the data source so that it returns coherent data
2. add an intermediate normalisation pass to your pipeline to handle this
3. or try both formats in sequence e.g.

```py
try: # try to parse 4 digit years
    df_MR['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_MR['Date'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")
except ValueError: # fallback to 2 digits year
    df_MR['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_MR['Date'], format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

One more alternative is to not pass in a format at all, and hope that pandas will get it right. Since both your date formats aren in DMY order, you could try `pd.to_datetime(dt, dayfirst=True)`.

Comment: this won't work if the formats are jumbled or are not in the specific order unfortunately

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to say. As long as they're unambiguous you can certainly attempt any number of format strings (though you probably want to loop over if you have more than 2). And if they're ambiguous... there's no helping you.

Comment: if the format of the column is `"%d-%m-%Y", "%d/%m/%y", "%d-%m-%Y"` this won't work

Comment: Then you do this for each and every row individually instead of by bulk.